# Display array format image from database in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I was trying to create one database to store images. It stores the URL of that image and the insertion is working fine.But it saves in array format as `["light.jpg"]`. Now I want to display the image stored in the database but it just shows image icon and not display the image. The image is stored in the image folder inside the public folder.

Below I attach my code:

**Form Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
            'filename' => 'required',
            'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    if($request->hasfile('filename'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('filename') as $image)
        {
            $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);  
            $data[] = $name;  
        }
     }

     $form= new Form();
     $form->filename=json_encode($data);
     $form->save();
     return back()->with('success', 'Your images has been successfully');
 }
 public function show()
 {
    $users = DB::select('select * from forms');
    return view('display',['users'=>$users]);
 }
```

**Insert page**

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{csrf_field()}}

        <div class="input-group control-group increment" >
          <input type="file" name="filename[]" class="form-control">
          <div class="input-group-btn"> 
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clone hide">
          <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
            <input type="file" name="filename[]" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-btn"> 
              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:10px">Submit</button>

  </form>        
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">      
    $(document).ready(function() {    
      $(".btn-success").click(function(){ 
          var html = $(".clone").html();
          $(".increment").after(html);
      });

      $("body").on("click",".btn-danger",function(){ 
          $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
      });    
    });
</script>
```

**Display Page:**

```
 @foreach ($users as $user)
     <img src="{{ url('images/$user->filename') }}"/>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
 @php $images = json_decode($user->filename,true); @endphp
   @if(is_array($images) && !empty($images))
   @foreach ($images as $image)
     <img src="{{ url('images/'.$image) }}"/>
   @endforeach
   @endif
@endforeach
```

if you save you images as json format this is the way . so i have put if condition also now check

Comment: Tq for the answer @Hamelraj .. but it shows Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  :(

Comment: @AlmiraEnterprise i have put if condition also now check

Comment: same..it does not display the image

Comment: after foreach `@foreach ($users as $user)` plz do loke this `{{ dd($user) }}` ans show me what you will get

Comment: {#205 ▼
  +"id": 2
  +"filename": "["download-1.jpg"]"
  +"created_at": "2018-11-05 02:58:34"
  +"updated_at": "2018-11-05 02:58:34"
}

Comment: it display like this

Comment: this is correct , plz inspect your web page and check your image path and let me know ??

Comment: the image is store under public folder -> image folder ->myimage

Comment: if image not display then you have to check this path is correct  `<img src="{{ url('images/$image') }}"/>` or you go to `public/images` folder and check wtr u having those images

Comment: plz check my answer now `url('images/'.$image)`

Comment: @AlmiraEnterprise ok ??

Comment: its work for me.Thanks alot and sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

In blade template you're inserting json format in img src but instead you should insert single filename. you can see that your filenames are stored as json so you need to decode json format and run foreach for every filename just like below.

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
   @php $filenames = json_decode($user->filename); @endphp
   //filenames are decoded now and you can use the foreach loop just like below
   @foreach ($filenames as $singlefilename)    
     <img src="{{ url('images/' . $singlefilename) }}"/>
   @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Hope it will help you